# How to approach designing this specific calendar table report

Tags: powerbi

First, I am a novice in PowerBI. I am trying to create a report similar to the one below. The records in data source have columns with Start Date and End Date. I need to make horizontal axis having 365 cells for every day of the year, and on vertical axis having types of records (based on a column with type), cells would be quantities with aggregates of rows of different types.

The problem is I am not sure how to start with this - how to have days on the horizontal axis? how to handle having just Start date and End date?

From the first try it seems that I can achieve this with Table visualization, but perhaps some other component would be easier?

I've got my queries prepared, the problem is with visualization.

[image]

Comment: In Power BI you can use a [matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-matrix-visual) for such kind of visualizations (your type field for rows, date for columns and quantity for values), but currently the maximum number of columns in a matrix is limited to about 100, so you can't directly achieve this (and frankly such visualization is not very practical). If you use a table, it must have 365/366 columns, named accordingly.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov I would need to have all of the columns visible from the start. How you would approach this yourself? Table? Can I automate creating columns somehow, or do I need to create them manually?

Comment: "All of the columns visible" means that on a full HD monitor, you will have about 3 pixels width to visualize the quantity. You simply can't show so much data at once. That's why I said it's not practical. You will have to scroll, but normally the data is shown vertically, not horizontally, so dates should be rows in a table, not columns. Put your types as columns, and make dates as rows. Create a hierarchy for drill down, so the user can see quantities per year, and drill down in individual year to see per month quantities, then in individual month to see daily data.

Comment: Oh, perhaps I have not been clear enough - they need to be visible, but do not need to be visible all at once on the screen - obviously there's need for scrolling. Problem is that business wants something similar to what they already have, and what they have can be seen on the screenshot. This is a layout similar also to other system they have, and intuitively reminds a calendar.

Answer (score 1):

To get the day level view you are looking for, it's better to use a matrix visualization. You can follow the following steps:

1. Create a matrix visualization
2. Use the Dates field in the "Columns"
3. Hover over the visual, and four arrow shapes will pop up
   i. Up arrow
   ii. Down arrow
   iii. Two down arrows
   iv. Split arrow
4. Click on the Split arrow till you get the visual you are looking for

Hope this helps.

Edit: As suggested in the comments by Andrey, Matrix visual cant't handle more than 100 columns. But you should be still able to leave it at a month level and if someone wants to drill through into a particular month, they can do so by clicking on the month value. This will let them see the day level information of that particular month (This can be enabled, by clicking on the down arrow in the arrow list).

Comment: The matrix visual can't handle this number of columns.

Comment: Oops! Missed that. Added an edit to address this. Thanks for pointing it out :)